# Template with struct

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct, binary-search-tree

I am designing a Binary Search Tree which allows user to enter value of any data-type, not just **int**.
To achieve this,i am trying to use template with a struct.
I defined my struct as follows

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    T info;
    struct node *right;
}*root;
```

Now i am trying use this in a class called BST(binary search Tree)

```
template <class T>
class bst
{
    public: 
    void insert(node *,node *);
    void inorder(node *);
};
```

But the compiler is throwing the error,
**template declaration of 'node< T >* root'**.
How can i use template with struct variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare `root` after a template class declaration, because the template argument can't be deduced, you could:

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    T info;
    struct node *right;
};

node <int> * root;
```

and you should appoint the template parameter type when you use `node`, such as:

```
template <class T>
class bst
{
    public: 
    void insert(node<T>*, node<T>*);
    void inorder(node<T>*);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    // […]
} *root;
```

You can't declare an object without a type. `node` is a template, not a type -- which type should `root` have?
 I believe you wanted to declare it inside `bst`:

```
template <class T>
class bst
{
    node<T>* root; 
    //  ^^^
    // Supply the appropriate template arguments

    // ... or use a typedef:
    using node_type = node<T>; 

    // […]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use typedef to have your Node type defined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct node
{
    node *left;
    T info;
    node *right;

    typedef node<T>* root;
};

int main()
{
   node<int>::root root = new node<int>();
   cout<<typeid(root).name()<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is showing the following error.  **T does not name a type**

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Pradeep my earlier answer was wrong as I misunderstood the question, check now.